# How to print my database output with nodejs and pug?

Tags: node.js, pug

I am trying to output a list of names from the database using NodeJS and PUG (ex Jade). For some reason, it only outputs an empty list. Please check the code below.

The layout for the input form

```
//Students.pug
extends layout

block content
form(action='/students', method='POST')
    input(type='hidden', name='_csrf', value=_csrf)
    .form-group
        label(for='fullname') Name
        input.form-control(type='text',name='fullname', id='fullname', 
        placeholder='name', autofocus, autocomplete='name' ,required)
        button.btn.btn-success(type='submit')
            i.fas.fa-user-plus.fa-sm
            | Add
```

SCHEMA
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');

```
    const studentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
fullName: {
    type: String
}
});

const Student = mongoose.model('Student', studentSchema);


module.exports = Student;
```

Controller

```
const express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Student = require('../models/student');


router.get('/', (req, res) => {
res.render('students');

});

router.post('/',(req, res) => {
InsertRecord(req, res);

});

function InsertRecord(req, res){
var student = new Student();
student.fullName = req.body.fullname;
student.save((err, doc) => {
    if (!err)
        res.redirect('students/list');
    else {
        console.log(' Error during insertion: '+ err);
    }
});

 }

router.get('/list', (req, res) => {
Student.find((err, docs) => {
    if (!err) {
        res.render('list', {
            list:docs

        });
    }
    else {
        console.log('Error in retrieving students: '+ err);
    }
});
 });

 module.exports = router;
```

And the /list page where the data should be listed
    extends layout

```
block content
 ul
 for fullName in list
    li= fullName.list
```

Everything works, the form localhost/students, submits the data to the database, the only issue I encounter is printing it out. 
Thank you in advance for your time!

Answer (score 0):

After some more try and fail
Here is the solution:
    extends layout

```
block content
ul
for student in list
    li= student.fullName
```

Answer (score 0):

In the template where you're looping over the list and outputting the names you're referencing `fullName.list` but I see no `.list` property on your mongoose model.
It should really be `fullName.fullName`. Id suggest changing the `fullName` to `student` so that its more understandable.